# Bash script for Docker container in Windows returns "Unknown target"

Tags: linux, bash, shell, docker, docker-for-windows

I've downloaded a repository that contains a .sh script to open a Docker container. I'm running Windows 10 with Docker Toolbox (rather than the full version, which has some Hyper-V issues) and its associated shell, and I've tried running the script both in that and in git-bash (which is based on MinGW/mintty), and in both cases I get

```
$ ./build-image.sh
Unknown target
```

Here's the full script, lightly redacted for privacy:

```
case $1 in
    keras_base)
        docker build -f docker/keras_base docker -t foo:keras_base
        ;;
    keras_branch)
        git archive HEAD > bar.tar
        cp bar.tar docker/keras_branch
        branch=$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD)
        docker build docker/keras_branch -t "foo:keras_${branch}"
        docker tag "foo:keras_${branch}" "XXXXXXXXXXX.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/foo:keras_${branch}"
        ;;
    *)
        echo Unknown target "$1"; exit 1
        ;;
    esac
```

Answer (score 0):

In a classic case of [rubber-duck debugging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging), writing this out helped me see the answer: the Unknown target argument is right there in the script, indicating that I hadn't given it an argument. Specifically, in bash scripts the arguments are zero-indexed prefixed by dollar signs, so $0 is the name of the script, and $1, $2, etc. are additional arguments. The first line `case $1 in` checks if $1 - the argument after the filename - is one of "keras_base" or "keras_branch". If it's not, or not provided, it returns `Unknown target`.